# Why are maximally entangled continuous variable states not physical?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, research-level

I have been going through this paper: **https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9908056**

There in, just after eq (1), it's mentioned that maximally entangled continuous variable states are not physical. Why is that so? Are discrete- variable states un-physical as-well?

Comment: Having given the paper a quick glance I think it is the same problem you almost always get when the words 'continuous' and 'maximal' appear in the same sentence; trying to put a system with a continuous degree of freedom into a single exact state is impossible, so we can never really be in the extremal state, although we can approximate it as well as we like.

Comment: So, is discrete maximally entangled state physically possible?

Comment: @BySymmetry Not really, see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

There is no "maximally entangled" CV (continuous variable) state. Pure entangled CV states have a parameter $r$ which measures their degree of entanglement. The maximally entangled state amounts to taking $r\to\infty$, but this limit is not  a physical state.

Even more, increasing $r$ means that the state has more and more energy. Since the amount of energy (in the universe, system, whatever) is bounded, it makes sense to introduce a cutoff to the (average) amount of energy in the system. Such an energy cutoff is also required mathematically, since otherwise all kind of quantities are not well-behaved.

For systems with a finite-dimensional Hilbert space there is no such problem, since everything is bounded anyway, and limits of states in the space are in the space as well.